# SignalR Groups simultaneously connections limitations

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr, signalr-hub

I've completed a chat application in signalr with user join based on a group Id.

The user access the webchat using a link "http://host/Index/{GroupId}/{UserId}", everyting works perfect until more than 5 people are connected in the same group.

I've looked on gitHub about connection limitations for SignalR but i didn't found anything about group connection limitations. Does anybody have an ideea?

After i've tried on multiple computers i've arrived at a number of 9 simultaneously connections

Comment: Where are you hosting the page?

Comment: As per http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/supported-platforms (look at the supported IIS versions) IIS 6 is not supported. It's not worth trying to figure out what's going on when you are using an unsupported version of IIS.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. They were very usefull because i've investigated much more on the server side and the version off iis that we used for testing was an iis express and i've found that it does not support more than 10 persons per connection. So we moved to iis 8. Thank you again